# Socket.io 1.0 Middleware join room not working properly

Tags: node.js, join, socket.io, middleware

I tried to add new socket to some rooms in a middleware, but it seems not working while a first emit haven't be done for a socket(client side). When a socket (client side) send a 'message' event  it will then work and be part of the room.
Is it a normal behavior? 
Am I mandatory to join room in 'connection' event?

app.js (server side)

```
var app = require('http').createServer(function (req, res){
  res.end('no rest');
});

var io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(7076);


io.use(function(socket, next){
  socket.join('toto');
  next();
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (data) {
    socket.to('toto').emit('message', data);
  });
});
```

Comment: This QA is a little messy and can't probably help anyone. Delete it ?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>According to the [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#joining-and-leaving), `socket.to('toto').emit...` syntax is not correct</strike>. You should use one of the following forms:

#### send everyone in "toto" room:

```
io.to('toto').emit('message', data);
```

#### send everyone in "toto" room except the sender:

```
socket.broadcast.to('toto').emit('message', data);
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve the problem: In fact  `socket.to('toto').emit('message', data);` does work according to the [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#to(room:string):socket)  my question is the socket is not part of the room while `socket.on('message'function(data){})` is called

Comment: Yes, you're right. `socket.to(...)` is a correct syntax as well, my appologies... But I put `socket.to('toto').emit('message', data);` in the very beginning of `connection` event handler, and it emits fine. You may try `console.log(socket.rooms)` for more convenient debugging

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem wasn't on the server side at all... It was my client that i didn't describe. 
When clicked on a button to send a message here is the function called

```
function messageManagement(cb)
    {
        var message = $('#message_text').val();
        if (!message || message.length == 0)
            message = 'I am watching you';
        socketClient.emit('message', {message:message});
        socketClient.on('message', function (data){
            console.log(data.messsage);
            drawMessage(data);
        });
    }
```

As you can see each time the client emit a message it also register to the response event. So each time I emit a message a registered one more time to same event... It was messy so i changed this and it worked..